# How to use accents on odoo 10

Tags: utf-8, odoo, odoo-10, accent-sensitive

I'm trying to use accent while creating my odoo module in french. 
in my xml files, I have: UTF-8 encoding like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

but the code always generate errors when i use Accents!

Comment: @Esther , for example, this code generate errors because of accent on **prenom**   </br>`class Eleve(models.Model):</br>
     _name = 'res.users.eleve'</br>

     nom = fields.Char("Nom")</br>
     prenom =  fields.Char("Prénom")</br>
     matricule = fields.Char("Matricule")</br>
     date_nais = fields.Date("Date de naissance")</br>
     classe_id = fields.Many2one("res.users.classe","Classe")`</br>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML coding looks fine (same as it's used in core, such as the `l10_fr` module)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

This leads me to believe you may need to set the encoding in the Python side. You shouldn't need to do anything but specify the encoding at the top of your file(s):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: "module dietfact no translation for language fr" I have this mistake!!

Comment: thant you!! you have resolved my problem!! plse vote